# Using if to get Splunk result from another index

Tags: splunk, splunk-query

I want to determine and return the process name from another search. Is there any command that can fulfill the requirements below?

```
index=index_A source=source_A
| timechart span=10m MAX(count) as result
| eval temp=if(result > 150 ,1,0) 
| streamstats sum(temp) AS tempsum window=2 
| eval Alert=if(tempsum == 2 , 1,0)
| eval process_name = if Alert==1 get result from [search index=index_A source=source_A .... return process_name]
| fields _time,result,Alert, process_name
```

Comment: Do you have any sample data you can share? I suspect there's a simpler way to get what you're looking for up in the initial search. If not there, a `join` will *likely* get what you're looking for - but some sample data will be necessary to determine that

Answer (score 0):

Without sample data, this is *only* a guess, but this `join` form should work:

```
index=ndxA sourcetype=srctpA
| timechart span=10m MAX(count) as result
| eval temp=if(result > 150 ,1,0) 
| streamstats sum(temp) AS tempsum window=2 
| eval Alert=if(tempsum == 2 , 1,0)
| join Alert
    [| index=ndxB sourcetype=srctpB process_name=*
    | stats count by process_name
    | eval Alert=if(match(process_name,"this_is_a_1"),1,0)
    | fields - count ]
```